# No such entity with id = 40 vendor/magento/framework/Exception/NoSuchEntityException.php:58

Tags: magento2, category, exception, no-such-entity-exception

Hi I have this problem when I delete a category from admin area.
If a user clicks on a url of a deleted product/category, or if he manually enters the id of the non-existent category, he generates a no such entity id exception.
I Check in database in all table and colunm and no found deleted category id.
If i check var/report see this

{"0":"No such entity with id = 40","1":"#1 Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository->get() called at [app/code/Manadev/LayeredNavigation/FilterTemplates/Category/TextSingleSelect.php:81]

Is third part extension and the code is this

```
public function prepare(ProductCollection $productCollection, Filter $filter) {
    $name = $filter->getData('param_name');
    $query = $productCollection->getQuery();
    $appliedCategory = false;

    if (($appliedCategoryId = $this->requestParser->readSingleValueInteger($name)) !== false) {
        $query->getFilterGroup('layered_nav')->addOperand($this->factory->createLayeredCategoryFilter(
            $name, [$appliedCategoryId]));

        /* @var $appliedCategory Category */
        $appliedCategory = $this->categoryRepository->get($appliedCategoryId,$this->storeManager->getStore()->getId());
    }


    $query->addFacet($this->factory->createChildCategoryFacet($name, $appliedCategory,
        $filter->getData('hide_filter_with_single_visible_item')));
}
```

**This string $appliedCategory = $this->categoryRepository->get($appliedCategoryId,$this->storeManager->getStore()->getId()); give me a problem because if no found getId() give me ecception maybe with control can fix this?**

I think that's how I fixed it

**use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory;**
**RedirectFactory $resultRedirectFactory in the constructor**

```
try {
                $appliedCategory = $this->categoryRepository->get($appliedCategoryId, $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId());
            } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException $e) {
                // Set appliedCategory to null
                $appliedCategory = null;
                // Redirect to custom 404 page
                $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
                $resultRedirect->setPath('no-route');
                return $resultRedirect;
            }
```

Comment: Why don’t you wrap the `$this->categoryRepository->get()` in a `try/catch` block?

Comment: @fantasticrice ty for idea